# SourceTree on Windows: GitHub personal access token (PAT) issue

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

Had to change my GitHub PAT (really was switching from password to PAT) and command line git worked fine, but could not get SourceTree to re-ask the password although followed standard procedure (Sourcetree menu > Preferences > Accounts).

Answer (score 5):

What helped: had to manually delete the GitHub entry (two lines) from c:\Users{your_name_here}\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\passwd and next time SourceTree asked the password again and I was able to input the new PAT.